# patching actionscript without constantly rebuilding swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, swfobject

How can I patch actionscript without constantly rebuilding sfw?
There is a fairly large actionscript project that I need to modify and resulting swf is used on a live site. The problem I have is that I need to make quick small updates to the swf and it's not acceptable to update the swf on live site ten time a day (I don't control that part, I need to ask another person to put the result on live site).
What options do I have to workaround that issue? I'm a complete noob when it comes to actionscript and all flash related stuff and I'm not even sure what is possible and what isn't. I'm thinking about the following approaches, which ones are possible/acceptable?

Imagine that live site is on `www.livesite.com/game.html` and this page loads `www.livesite.com/flashgame.swf`. In that `flashgame.swf` among many others there is a class `com/livesite/Magic.as` that gets instantiated and instance of that class has a member variable `xxx123` of class `com/livesite/MagicWork.as`. I only need to modify this `MagicWork` class. Now, I simply modify it, build and ask to put updated `flashgame.swf` live. So, I want to avoid that manual step.

All my ideas can be split in two basic approaches: 1) keep flashgame.swf totally unmodified and then load flashgame.mod.swf that contains alternative implementation of that `MagicWork` class, then using javascript access internals of instance of that Magic class and update its `xxx123` member to be an instance of `MagicWork` class from `flashgame.mode.swf`. I'd need to modify `game.html` to load my javascript so that my js file would load `flashgame.mod.swf` and patch code inside `flashgame.swf`. By patching I mean javascript-style overwriting of Magic.xxx123 to a new value. `flashgame.mode.swf` would ideally reside on my own host that I control. Is that kind of stuff possible, if not what's not possible?
2) I could make one-time change in `flashgame.swf` so that it would effectively load itself my own code at runtime and patch it's `xxx123` member. Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you need to republish to the live production site so many times?!

Comment: @Brian I don't need to, but if I ever have to I don't want to ask 10 times manually. I'm working on early stage project that in part is directed by how it works on a live site. So, if there is any issue it can be fixed quickly and updated right away. The point is that it's enabled for 0.001% users for example, so it won't have effect on all ppl, and it's ok to make mistakes there.

Comment: Okay, then the solution to your problem is to get direct access to the "0.001% live site" so you can update the swf -- not change the code to load a dependency swf from pavelscustomworld.org.

Comment: No, it's actually is the point to load that way as a module. That's the way it will be eventually. Basically bigger `flashgame.swf` project lives on its own and the `mod` is separate and can be updated independently. To separate them isn't only a "weird" way to solve problem of manual updates, but also is the way it has to be eventually anyways.

Comment: Are you thinking about a runtime shared library by any chance? The Flash Player has the ability to load external code libraries at runtime which can be separate from the primary .swf file you're playing. But the external libraries still do need to be compiled and deployed on a public web server.

Comment: @PranavN. that sounds like what I want!! Can you explain a bit more, and make it an answer? I'm ok to put it publicly (but it has to be different host). Main swf could be modified to load my mod.swf from some other host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had already written a note about loading runtime shared libraries previously. I'll put the most essential parts of the process here, and add a link to the full article at the end.

You need to tag your main application entry point in the following manner.

```
[Frame(factoryClass="Preloader")]
public class Main extends Sprite
{

}
```

Then create a class called Preloader.

```
public class Preloader
{

    public function Preloader()
    {
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.loader_completeHandler);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, this.loader_ioErrorHandler);
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("math.swf");
        var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
        loader.load(request, context);
    }

    private function loader_completeHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        var mainClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("Main") as Class;
        var mainInstance:Main = new mainClass();
        this.addChild(mainInstance);
    }
}
```

The full implementation of the Main class is like this.

```
[Frame(factoryClass="Preloader")]
public function Main()
{
    var integer:IntegerArithmetic = new IntegerArithmetic(); // Type declared in math.swf
    var operand1:int = 10;
    var operand2:int = 10;
    var result:int = integer.add(operand1, operand2);
}
```

**Deploying Runtime Shared Libraries**

The confusing bit about using a runtime shared library is realizing that the SWF has to be extracted from the SWC at the time of deploying the application. This was not immediately obvious and I ended up spending days placing a compiled SWC file in various locations and wondering why the application was unable to load it at runtime. An obscure article on the Adobe website made explicit this particular step and set things straight.

The full article along with the same example is available at http://www.notadesigner.com/runtime-shared-libraries-with-plain-actionscript/.